# No of pairs of integers $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+2y^2<25$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

[image]

Using [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), one can easily find out the pairs (a,b) that sum upto 25, then 24 then 23.....and eliminate all 'a's and 'b's which are not squares and all 'b's which are odd. But is this the only way? Is there no better way? Please help.

Comment: In this case, it's easy to just plot the zone and count the number of points with integer coordinates ...

Comment: No need for starts and bars. Note that $$x^2 + 2y^2 \leq 24 \implies y^2 \leq 12 \implies |y| \leq 3$$,  so it is enough to check the cases $y = 0 \to 3$, and find how many $x$ work in each case. Then you can also include negative numbers with the obvious fact that $(x,y)$ is a solution, if and only if $(\pm x , \pm y)$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments correctly note, since we know that $|y|\leq3$, we can simply check all the values by hand.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
y&x\\\hline
-3&-2,-1,0,1,2\\\hline
-2&-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\\\hline
-1&-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\\\hline
0&-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\\\hline
1&-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\\\hline
2&-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\\\hline
3&-2,-1,0,1,2\\\hline
\end{array}

So there are a total of $\color{red}{55}$ pairs.